# Archive a big folder with large number of smaller and big files

Tags: filesystems, compression, zip, tar, archiving

I need to archive a folder from `normal drive` into `tape` in organization data storage and might retrieve them in the later stage. My scenario is

- a large folder with size from 10 GB to 300 GB
- The folder contains up to half millions smaller files (less than 100 KB), thousands of median files (10-100 MB) and several big files (up to 5 GB)
- Most of files are compressed and no storage constrain in the tape so I don't need to further compression.
- Don't need encryption
- The operation system is Linux (ubuntu) in the cluster. The bandwidth should be a problem for me to transfer files.

Archiving all files into one file would be the best option in my scenario.

My questions are

- which type of format is the best option (zip or tar).
- Any options for the specific files can be used to speed up archiving.

Comment: No experience with tape backups, but when I want to backup a directory, I just pack it (using zip or tar or whatever), just for the sake of having a single file which copies much faster (at least on a Windows PC) than many small files.

Comment: i see no other tool than *tar* for preserving metadata